# CSS span::before for text animations is not working despite using content to flip through

Tags: html, css

I am trying text animations on my home page and the text slides are not working. I have tried other methods but span: before seems to be almost workable. However, I see the code is exactly working on an Sublime Text but does not work for me in Visual Studio.

The CSS

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: rgb(65, 51, 187);
    font-family:Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;


}
.wrapper{
   position: absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

}

.wrapper h2{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    font-size: 60px;

}
.wrapper p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 35px;
}
.wrapper a{
    background: crimson;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10 px 25 px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;

}

span::before{
    content: '';
    animation: animate infinite 8s;

}
@keyframes animate{
    0% {
        content: 'A programmer';
    }
    33%{
        content: 'An architect';
    }
    66%{
        content: 'A developer';
    }100%
    {
        content: 'An Automater';
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "style3.css"
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "wrapper">
        <h2>I am a <span></span></h2>
        <p>This is a trial for working out sliding texts</p>
            <a href="#">Contact me </a>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I have displayed the content but it still does not work.The problem could mostly be in the CSS Span::before. I know probably I am missing something very minimal. Please assist.

Comment: What browser(s) do you want this to work for? It shows the changing content on Chrome/Windows10 but content in keyframes does not work in Safari/IOS. For a general solution you'll need a different approach. (BTW you are missing a closing bracket on the link element).

Comment: I am using chrome.

Comment: You snippet is working for me on Chrome/Windows10. Your original code would not work as it's missing a closing bracket on the link element.

Comment: That was hard to spot. Finally it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing a pseudo element's content does not work in some browsers (e.g. Safari on IOS) so here is a more general method, animating the opacity of span elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "style3.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: rgb(65, 51, 187);
    font-family:Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;


}
.wrapper{
   position: absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

}

.wrapper h2{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    font-size: 60px;

}
.wrapper p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 35px;
}
.wrapper a{
    background: crimson;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10 px 25 px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;

}

h2 div, h2 div span {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span {
    animation: animate infinite 8s;
    animation-delay: calc((var(--n) - 1) * 2s);
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

h2 span:nth-child(1) {
  --n: 1;
}

h2 span:nth-child(2) {
  --n: 2;
}

h2 span:nth-child(3) {
  --n: 3;
}

h2 span:nth-child(4) {
  --n: 4;
}

@keyframes animate{
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25.1% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "wrapper">
        <h2>I am &nbsp; <div><span>A programmer</span><span>An architect</span><span>A developer</span><span>An automater</span></div></h2>
        <p>This is a trial for working out sliding texts</p>
            <a href="#">Contact me </a>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```